# How to round a very small floating point number with trailing zeros?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, numbers, rounding

Currently my code renders the number:

```
x = 0.000092627861766
p x
```

as something like a BigInt format such that:

```
=> 9.0e-05
```

Is there a method I can call on the variable to return a rounded floating point number (in either number or string format) such that:

```
x.some_method
# Always show N number of digits after the initial decimal point.
=> 0.00009263 
OR 
=> "0.00009263"
```

Comment: What is the requirement? A) Always show N number of digits after decimal point, or B) always show N number of digits that are > 0 after decimal point?

Comment: @Casper I've edited my OP in response to your question. For clarity: I'd like A) To always show N number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set the number of digits to be shown:

```
p "%0.08f" % x # => "0.00009263"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new method to do that.
I use BigDecimal just for accuracy and prevent unexpected result,
but I think you can do the probably the same thing in Float:

```rb
require 'bigdecimal'
class BigDecimal
  def round_after_n(n)
    round(self.exponent.abs + n + 1)
  end
end
x = BigDecimal('0.000092627861766')
#  => 0.926279e-4 
x.round_after_n(5).to_s('F')
#  => "0.0000926279"
```